# Problems with Go folder layout

Tags: go

I am having problems getting Go tests to run.  I followed the [go instructions](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

#### .zshrc

```
export GOPATH=/Users/chris/Projects/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH
```

#### sample app files => /Users/chris/Projects/go/src/github.com/chris/roundrobin

```
./main.go
./roundrobin.go
./roundrobin_test.go
```

#### main.go

```
package main

import "github.com/chris/schedule"

func main(teamCount int) {
    http.HandleFunc('/', func(w http.ResponseWriter, r, *http.Request) {
        gameSchedule := schedule.NewSchedule()
    }
}
```

#### roundrobin/schedule.go

```
package roundrobin

// nothing imported here for now
...
```

#### roundrobin/schedule_test.go

```
package roundrobin

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/chris/roundrobin/schedule"
)
...
```

#### try to build (only fails if the main file exists)

I was able to build until I changed to the github.com/username/ folder layout

```
➜  roundrobin  go build
can't load package: package github.com/chris/roundrobin: found packages main (main.go) and roundrobin (schedule.go) in /Users/chris/Projects/go/src/github.com/chris/roundrobin
```

#### try to run tests

```
➜  roundrobin  go test
# github.com/chris/roundrobin
schedule_test.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/chris/roundrobin/schedule" in any of:
  /usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/chris/roundrobin/schedule (from $GOROOT)
  /Users/chris/Projects/go/src/github.com/chris/roundrobin/schedule (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    github.com/chris/roundrobin [setup failed]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have two files (`main.go` and `schedule.go`) in the root. They both have different package names. One has `package main`, the other has `package schedule`. You need to move the `schedule` one into the `schedule` subfolder or change `package schedule` to `package main` in `schedule.go`. Remember, your `import` statements are physical folder paths. So if you're importing `/roundrobin/schedule`.. there needs to be a `schedule` folder in the root of your project.

Comment: Thanks Simon! That solved the package problem.  Seems pretty obvious now.

Comment: you also need to change `PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH` to `PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` (and though you're not using it, keep in mind that `$GOPATH` *can* contains multiple entries just like `$PATH`)

Comment: Thanks Jim.  Right now everything compiles and tests pass, but I will later make the tweak and see what happens.